# Akka PingPong example wont run in scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I'm trying to run the ping-pong example from Akka's documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#introduction). When I run it in the ScalaFiddle through Akka's site, everything works as expected. When I copy/paste and run it in an IntelliJ scala worksheet, I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class A$A14$A$A14$Pinger for arguments []`. What is going wrong here? Code included below.

My worksheet is not "running in a compiler process" as per [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9229). Otherwise, I have tried running in "eclipse compatibility mode" as well as in "REPL mode" and "Interactive Mode." Finally, the "Make project before run" setting has no effect.

```
import akka.actor.{ ActorSystem, Actor, ActorRef, Props, PoisonPill }
import language.postfixOps
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case object Ping
case object Pong

class Pinger extends Actor {
  var countDown = 100

  def receive = {
    case Pong =>
      println(s"${self.path} received pong, count down $countDown")

      if (countDown > 0) {
        countDown -= 1
        sender() ! Ping
      } else {
        sender() ! PoisonPill
        self ! PoisonPill
      }
  }
}

class Ponger(pinger: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Ping =>
      println(s"${self.path} received ping")
      pinger ! Pong
  }
}

val system = ActorSystem("pingpong")

val pinger = system.actorOf(Props[Pinger], "pinger")

val ponger = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Ponger], pinger), "ponger")

import system.dispatcher
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 millis) {
  ponger ! Ping
}
```

Comment: do you have try to use`Props(new Pinger())`,`(Props(new Ponger(pinger))`

Comment: Making your suggested change removes the error, but it still doesn't function correctly. It writes out `akka.actor.Cancellable = akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder@44d52de2` instead of a series of the println calls.

Comment: `Cancellable` is `scheduleOnce`'s  return result , it should be no problem.   the worksheet have not `println` nothing, i think the worksheet  is not good for concurrently support .